# Stop javascript from implicitly converting string to int

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, type-conversion

So I have a `datapoint` object with fields `date`(string) and `count`(integer). I'm trying to add them to arrays with some JS inside of my `show` view. Everything is working well - except that my `date` string is being converted to a series of JS arithmetic. For example: a value of `"2015-05-05"` is getting converted to `2005`. Code follows:

```
<h1 id="chart"></h1>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var counts = ['Count']
        var dates = ['x']
        <% @chart.datasource.datapoints.each do |c| %>
          dates.push( <%= c.date %> )
          counts.push( <%= c.count %> )
        <% end %>
        chart(counts, dates);
</script>
```

Comment: `dates.push( "<%= c.date %>" )` wrap it with quotes to make it string... otherwise `2015-05-05 = 2005`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing quotes:

```
var counts = ['Count']
var dates = ['x']
<% @chart.datasource.datapoints.each do |c| %>
  dates.push( "<%= c.date %>" )
  counts.push( <%= c.count %> )
<% end %>
chart(counts, dates);
```

Wrapping the value in quotes will force JS to consider it as a string primitive, rather than a number and arithmetic operators.